# programmatically changing UITableView section index

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 2 sections in a table view, but I only display one section at a time. It defaults to section 1 - the first section.

Is there way through code I can change the current section to 1 programmatically?

like say [tableView setSection:1]?

Comment: It's not clear why you would have sections if you only display one at a time. Do you sometimes display both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `[tableView reloadData]`, your table is reloaded, and each cells and sections too. So you must do three steps:

1. set a property indicating which section is selected.
2. ask for this property in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to return the cells of the section you want
3. and finally call `[tableView reloadData]`

Answer (score 0):

No, you must build that logic yourself.  So you'll end up with `if`'s in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and friends.

BTW, the first section has 'index' 0, so it's confusing to talk about a single section 1.